# How to pass a dynamic delimiter to csv marshalling in camel?

Tags: apache-camel

i want to pass a dynamic delimiter to the csv marshalling like below.

```
<marshal>
    <csv delimiter="${header.FIELD_DELIMITER}"/>
</marshal>
```

when i try as above i am getting this exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Delimiter must have a length of one!
    at org.apache.camel.model.dataformat.CsvDataFormat.configureDataFormat(CsvDataFormat.java:138)
    at org.apache.camel.model.DataFormatDefinition.getDataFormat(DataFormatDefinition.java:88)
    at org.apache.camel.model.DataFormatDefinition.getDataFormat(DataFormatDefinition.java:80)
    at org.apache.camel.model.MarshalDefinition.createProcessor(MarshalDefinition.java:158)
    at org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinition.createProcessor(ProcessorDefinition.java:460)
    at org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinition.createOutputsProcessor(ProcessorDefinition.java:429)
    at org.apache.camel.model.TryDefinition.createProcessor(TryDefinition.java:73)
    at org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinition.makeProcessor(ProcessorDefinition.java:500)t
    at org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinition.addRoutes(ProcessorDefinition.java:213)
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:909)
    ... 19 more
```

Comment: which version of camel are you using?

Comment: What delimiter you wanted to set? Let say you want to set delimiter '|', in that case before marshalling add a camel processor as set the Camel Header with 'delimiter' as its key and value as '|', and in csv Component use it like  ${in.header.delimiter}

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing this

```
<marshal>
    <csv delimiter="${header.FIELD_DELIMITER}"/>
</marshal>
```

You need to do this:

```
<toD uri="dataformat:csv:marshal?delimiter=${header.FIELD_DELIMITER}"/>
```

This is dynamic routing and you will need to use this whenever you want to create URIs on runtime based on runtime values.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that with marshal. However you can use the dataformat endpoint and the dynamic to pattern. See more details at:

- http://camel.apache.org/dataformat-component.html
- http://camel.apache.org/how-to-use-a-dynamic-uri-in-to.html